# A Combinatorics Problem Involving Some Badminton Players

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

In a badminton competition there are n players. All the players play with each other exactly once and each game has a result, i.e. win or lose. No tie is permitted. Now all the players enlist the name of some other players in the following manner - 
1. He enlists the name of all the players he defeated.
2. He enlists the names of the players who are defeated by the players whom he defeated.
For instance, a player A enlists the names of B and C if A defeats B and B defeats C.
 Prove that there exists at least  one such player A who has enlisted the names of all the other players.

Comment: I tried in the following way, using simple induction.

Comment: What does your last sentence mean?

Comment: Use the notations:-.    P(i) stands for the i-th player. Call P(i)#P(j) if P(i) defeats P(j). Now clearly, the statement is true for n=2. Now suppose , this is true for n=m players. Now, say P(k) is such a player who has the names of all the players in his list. Now, introduce a new player P(m+1). Now if he wins or loses all the matches then we are done. Again, suppose the case is not so but he loses to P(k). Again we are done. Now suppose P(m+1)#P(k) but P(o)#P(m+1) such that P(k)#P(o).Again we are done. Now the remaining case is P(m+1)#P(k) but there is nosuch P(k)#P(q) such that P(q)#P(m+1)

Comment: But remember there exists at least one P(r) such that P(r)#P(m+1). Otherwise P(m+1) wins all the matches and we are therefore, done. Now, P(r)#P(k) and P(r)#P(m+1). So, there exists P(m+1)#P(s) such that P(s)#P(r) ( Here we consider that P(m+1) has lost only one match, i.e. the limiting case). Again P(r)#P(k) and but there is one P(t)#P(r) and since P(m+1) loses only one match so P(m+1)#P(t). Therefore P(m+1) is the required player.

Comment: @Mike Earnest, am I right? Sorry for using too many notations.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is:

> Prove that there exists exactly one such player A.

Then it contradicts the question statement:

> ... there are n players ... all the players enlist the name of some other players ...

If we add in a condition like a unique maximum number of enlisted players, this seems to be a counterexample:

[image]

Here:

- A enlists B and C,
- B enlists C and A, and
- C enlists A and B.

Comment: you are correct. I think the question should be like this " Prove that there is at least one such player "

Comment: I have made the edit.